# SQL condition : if else statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database, if-statement, case

I am using this particular example

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

I want to get the list of customers who country name starts with Fr, if there are no customers in Fr% then I want to look for customers in country starting with Ger if there are no one in Ger% I want to look for customer with countries starting with Au% .

```
CREATE PROCEDURE cusBycon
AS
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Customers WHERE Country = "France") == 0 
BEGIN 
   IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Customers WHERE Country = "Germany") = 0 
   BEGIN
       SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Country = "Australia" as Country
   END
   ELSE
   BEGIN
       SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Country = "Germany" as Country
   END
END
ELSE
BEGIN
       SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Country = "France" as Country
END
GO;


EXEC cusBycon;
```

I am receiving the error "could not prepare statement". Is there an optimal way to perform the same.

Thank you

Comment: Don't use w3schools as a resource - it isn't authoritative. You should refer to MySQL's official documentation instead: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html

Comment: You should use `IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM Customers WHERE Country = 'France' )` instead of `SELECT COUNT(*) ... = 0` as it can return sooner without scanning the whole table or index.

Comment: The error is because MySQL only allows `IF` statements inside a `PROCEDURE`, not query batches.

Comment: In his defense the mysql docs can be somewhat opaque and w3schools has provided a sample database for him to work with here, making it easier to just start playing around with it.

Comment: The posted code is sql-server and can't simply be dropped into mysql

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: you have this question tagged as mySQL, but the Northwinds database isn't mySQL.  For instance, w3schools doesn't support `ORDER BY FIELD`, which mySQL would, among other differences.

---

I'm not sure I would go about it that way.  I think what I would use is a subquery, something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Country IN (
  SELECT Country FROM Customers
  WHERE Country IN ('France', 'Germany', 'Australia')
  ORDER BY FIELD(Country, 'France', 'Germany', 'Australia')
  LIMIT 1
)
```

In this case, I'm going to use `WHERE` to limit the interior query to only those three countries, and then I'm using `ORDER BY FIELD` to sort it in that specific order, and then finally `LIMIT 1` to return just the top record.  Then the outer query selects everything from the table where the country matches whatever was returned.

I say something like that because I can't test it.  w3schools doesn't seem to support `ORDER BY FIELD`.  So you can do something similar but a little more clunky:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Country IN (
  SELECT Country FROM (
    SELECT Country, 
      CASE WHEN Country = 'France' THEN 1 
        WHEN Country = 'Germany' THEN 2 
        ELSE 3 END
    FROM Customers 
    WHERE Country IN ('France', 'Germany', 'Australia')
    ORDER BY 2 LIMIT 1
  ) z
)
```

In this example I use `CASE WHEN` to generate a sort order for the countries, then `ORDER` them by that column, in this case using 2 (for field 2) since there's no name for the field, since I generated it.  I wrap that in a select because otherwise it will return two fields and the subquery (`WHERE Country IN`) is expecting only one argument passed to it.

Is that the result you were expecting?

---

A version to reflect your latest edit on the question, in the northwinds example database, using LIKE:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Country IN (
  SELECT Country FROM (
    SELECT Country, 
      CASE WHEN Country LIKE 'Fr%' THEN 1 
        WHEN Country LIKE 'Ger%' THEN 2 
        ELSE 3 END
    FROM Customers 
    WHERE (Country LIKE 'Fr%')
    OR (Country LIKE 'Ger%')
    OR (Country LIKE 'Au%')
    ORDER BY 2 LIMIT 1
  ) z
)
```

This would be simplified in mySQL (or managed code under SQL Server, or another rdms that supports REGEX):

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Country IN (
  SELECT Country FROM (
    SELECT Country, 
      CASE WHEN Country LIKE 'Fr%' THEN 1 
        WHEN Country LIKE 'Ger%' THEN 2 
        ELSE 3 END
    FROM Customers 
    WHERE Country REGEXP '^(Fr|Ger|Au%)'
    ORDER BY 2 LIMIT 1
  ) z
)
```

This example with REGEXP will not work on the Northwinds sample at w3schools, and I also have not tested it, since I would have to export the database to do so.

Comment: I tested it on w3schools, there is a type so maybe that is why you received an error. i tried testing it and if France and Germany is not present it still shows data, which should not happen. Thank you

Comment: The second query absolutely works, and there is no typo.  The first query is the one that gives an error, I would guess because the Northwinds database doesn't support `ORDER BY FIELD`.  In the second query I forgot to include the `WHERE Country IN ()` clause to limit it to ONLY those countries, because I was focused on that sort.  Check the edit I just made to the answer.

Comment: SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Country IN (
  SELECT Country FROM (
    SELECT Country, 
      CASE WHEN Country = 'France1' THEN 1 
        WHEN Country = 'Germany1' THEN 2 
        ELSE 3 END
    FROM Customers 
    WHERE Country IN ('France', 'Germany', 'Australia')
    ORDER BY 2 LIMIT 1
  ) 
)

Gives all the customers in Germany, which is not the expected behavior

Comment: Where is France1 coming from?  Or Germany1?  That's not in the code I have up there.  I have run it at w3, copying it straight from this answer, and produced the correct results.

Comment: An image of the code run at w3, pasted directly from this answer, returning results for France.  https://imgur.com/a/o5BbLsj